# Yii rules of listbox are not being validated

Tags: yii, listbox

I have a listbox in a form whichs writes into my database. There has to be a value selected. In my view a have:

```
<?php
                echo $form->radioButtonList($model, 'lidmaatschap',
                    array(  '75' => 'Lidmaatschap Vriend &euro; 75,-',
                            '1' => 'Lidmaaschap Vriend, ander bedrag' ),
                    array( 'separator' => '<br>' ) );
            ?>
```

In my model I have the rules set up which work for my text fields but I can't get the validation for my listbox to work. I tried:

```
array('lidmaatschap', 'required'),
```

and tried to compare it:

```
array('lidmaatschap', 'compare', 'compareValue' => '75'),
```

But it doesn't seem to recognize the listbox. When I use both ways on a textbox everything works just fine. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Did you check (maybe print in the bottom of list?) `$form->error($model,'lidmaatschap');`

Comment: Ah, you're right. Then it prints an error message. So it does get recognized. Thanks!